# Getting radio button value into jQuery

Tags: jquery, radio-button

I have a table with two radio buttons for each row, these buttons are approve and reject,
so for each row they'll have different name.

When I get the value of selected radio button into jquery the first choice will affect the rest, means if I choose approve for the first, no matter what I select for the rest their status becomes approved!

here are the codes:

jQuery:

```
var status=$('input:radio[name=status_input_+ID]:checked').val();
```

HTML:

```
<input name="status_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" type="radio" value="Approved">
Approve
<input name="status_input_<?php echo $id; ?>" type="radio" value="Rejected">
Reject
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this :

```
var status=$('input:radio[name="status_input_'+ID+'"]:checked').val();
```

value should be enclosed in quotes. Refer [this link](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

You have not put radio button name correctly in your code, you should use quotes in the name.

```
var status=$('input:radio[name="status_input_'+ID+'"]:checked').val();
```

I have edited your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdQEN/1/). Check it.